# Some of the outputs from cygwin just can not be read with bad encoding?

Tags: encoding, cygwin, character

I'm using cygwin on Win7-64bit, and with "zh_CN.UTF-8" as default locale setting.
Occasionally, some of the outputs from cygwin just can not be read with bad encoding like follows:

```
[junit] ▒▒▒▒: ▒Ҳ▒▒▒▒▒▒޷▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ can't
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Just get the solution. http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.weirdchars Change the Terminal Options of Text, choose character set as "GBK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.weirdchars

It's just caused by some Chinese character here.

Change the Terminal Options of Text, choose character set as "GBK". It works.

Answer (score 6):

Although sharajava have found a solution by himself, I have to say that this solution is not very preferable at least for me. The problem is if you change the Terminal Options of Text ("CharSet" of `mintty` actually) to "GBK", what will UTF-8 characters display on screen? They will be messy, unreadable code. I experimented on VIM, whether its chinese welcome text or UTF-8 encoded source code including chinese characters displays as unreadable code. It's not acceptable for me or, as I guess,  most people.

Finally I figured out a way to bypass the flaw of Windows command prompt (i.e. `cmd.exe`) and enabling `mintty` running DOS commands without suffering from messy codes. Here is my solution and may it be helpful.

Testing environment:
OS: Win7 64-bit Chinese Simplified
Cygwin: 64-bit
Command Prompt: default code-page 936

Configuration:

- Set locale of Cygwin to `zh_CN.UTF-8` as most people desired
- Add `Locale=zh_CN` and `Charset=UTF-8` to `.minttyrc` making `mintty` use UTF-8 as output encoding
- Add `cmd /c chcp 65001` to `.bashrc`

Now you are able to run DOS commands like `ipconfig`, `taskkill`, `help.exe` and `format.com` etc directly on `mintty`, even in companion with linux commands such as `less`,`grep`. Every time you login in bash, it will tell you `Active code page: 65001` meaning the output encoding of `cmd.exe` has been temporarily changed to UTF-8.

When code-page of `cmd.exe` is changed to 65001, `cmd.exe` will no longer use Chinese as hint text language (English instead) and Chinese directories are not supported either. This is a defect of `cmd.exe` and has nothing to do with `mintty`. Somehow, `mintty` manages to output Chinese characters which `cmd.exe` with cp65001 cannot. I can't explain this, anyway, it works.

To set locale of cygwin, you can add following code to your `.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

See also:
[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500)
[My application prints international characters but I only see gray boxes](https://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.weirdchars)

Comment: Finally I found a solution, thanks. I can confirm that it works also for win 7 with Swedish encoding (`sv_SE.UTF-8`), but I don't have to set `LC_ALL or LC_CTYPE` they are empty, `LANG` is set to `sv_SE.UTF-8` by cygwin from the installation.