# UTF-8 characters not displayed correctly in console

Tags: utf-8, clojure, console

I'm implementing a card game in Clojure and I want to use unicode characters to represent suits:

```
(def color-str "Maps card colors to strings"
  { :kreuz "♣", :grun "♠", :herz   "♥", :schell "♦" })
```

However instead of desired characters I get this result:

```
{:grun "ΓÖá", :herz "ΓÖÑ", :kreuz "ΓÖú", :schell "ΓÖª"}
```

Similarly, when I redefine `color-str` to:

```
(def color-str "Maps card colors to strings"
  { :kreuz \u2663, :grun \u2660, :herz \u2665, :schell \u2666 })
```

I get:

```
{:grun \ΓÖá, :herz \ΓÖÑ, :kreuz \ΓÖú, :schell \ΓÖª}
```

File is saved as UTF-8 without BOM. I already tried adding:

```
:javac-options ["-encoding utf8"]
:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"]
```

to the `project.clj` file but it didn't help. I know that console (Cygwin's Bash) is able to show those characters - when I copy-pasted `{ :kreuz "♣", :grun "♠", :herz   "♥", :schell "♦" }` directly into REPL it displayed them correctly.

What did I miss?

Comment: The character encoding of the console is set to something different than what Clojure thinks it is set to.

Comment: Thanks! Running `cmd /c chcp 65001` did solve the problem.

Comment: @maddening you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I hoped @Jesper post it but I can do it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character encoding of the console is set to something different than what Clojure thinks it is set to.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to run:

```
cmd /c chcp 65001
```

It sets default code page in console to UTF-8. By default CMD uses code page default to current language and localization settings e.g. [437 for United States](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html). Settings it to UTF-8 ([65001](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)) solves the issue.

I got the idea from 2nd answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510618/some-of-the-outputs-from-cygwin-just-can-not-be-read-with-bad-encoding) after @Jesper suggested that it's related to the console encoding.